# How to know if img tag fails to load

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to catch an HTTP error from a `WebView` when loading an `<img>` tag. In particular, if I load the following html, neither the `img.onerror` javascript method, nor the `onReceivedHttpError` method from the `WebViewClient`, which was introduced in API 23, are called.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <img src='null' id='image'>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way of detecting an HTTP error in a `WebView` in API < 23?

Comment: What kind of error do you want to hear?

Comment: An http error, like a 404 or something

Comment: What do you think is so wrong in your html that an error should be generated? And why javascript error? There is no javascript.

Comment: The `img` `src`; it doesn't exist, so the image should not be found